Why 'docusaurus' is not recognized as an internal or external command?
I am trying to run a simple React project
yarn start

yarn run v1.22.22
docusaurus start
'docusaurus' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Why?
yarn global list shows us
yarn global v1.22.22info "docusaurus@1.14.7" has binaries:docusaurus-startdocusaurus-builddocusaurus-publishdocusaurus-examplesdocusaurus-write-translationsdocusaurus-versiondocusaurus-rename-versionDone in 0.69s.

How can I solve this issue?
I am trying set up Docsaurus website,following the offical documentation
text
I am providing my dependancies,and I am curious how they should look like.
  "devDependencies": {
    "@algolia/client-search": "^4.24.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.511.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-providers": "3.511.0",
    "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt": "^3.511.0",
    "@babel/helper-get-function-arity": "^7.16.7",
    "@docusaurus/core": "^2.4.1",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "^2.4.1",
    "@docusaurus/theme-mermaid": "^2.4.1",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.21",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cli-progress": "3.12.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "configure-webpack": "file:plugins/configure-webpack",
    "eslint": "9.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "webpack": "5.93.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mermaid": "^10.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "rehype-katex": "5",
    "remark-math": "3"
  },

How should yarn provide more info of what really went wrong?

Try making sure  both docusaurus core and classic are installed localy in your project
yarn add @docusaurus/core @docusaurus/preset-classic

additionally see if it starts with
yarn add @docusaurus/core @docusaurus/preset-classic

If that doesn't work id check package.json to make sure the start script is in there. Also sometimes I just run yarn install --force to reinstall all the dependencies
